# Apple's display adapters over USB-C/Thunderbolt adapter

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, displayport, vga-adapter, dvi

I just got a new MBP, and I bought a [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MMEL2ZM/A/adapter-voor-thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-naar-thunderbolt-2), assuming I could use the [VGA](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-naar-vga-adapter), [DVI](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MB570Z/B/mini-displayport-naar-dvi-adapter) and [Ethernet](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MD463ZM/A/thunderbolt-naar-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) adapters that I already had, so I would only have to buy 1 adapter instead of 3 more expensive ones.

The ethernet adapter doesn't seem to work, and I can't get picture using the DVI or VGA adapters. I'm having trouble finding documentation - is that setup supposed to work? If so, what should I check?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it's "supposed" to work, but judging by the reviews on both Apple's own website and on Amazon, (two and three stars respectively), it's not doing so well.

[image]
[image]

There is however, the [Cable Matters Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt Adapter](http://radnex.us/cablematters-thunderbolt-3-2-adapter) that gets high reviews though (IMO) is not as good looking as the Apple design.  Though for me, it could look like a brick as long as it worked.

That said, generally speaking, I don't like converting signals, it's just another potential point of failure; instead I like going from "native connection to native connection" so it not only reduces the number of physical conversions, but the protocol conversions as well.  While this will be a sore spot with many of Apple customers that invested heavily in adapters for their previous generation MacBooks, the consensus is that USB-C is here to stay.

Your best bet is to put those older adapters up on eBay and get new ones.